# Pass linker flags in CMake for CPLEX

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, cplex, linker-flags

**In short:** I can't link my program that uses CPLEX with CMake, the linker doesn't seem to find a CPLEX library (`cplex`), but finds some others (`ilocplex`). From the command line, it does work.

**Detailed:**

For the program using CPLEX:

```
#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   IloEnv env;
   IloModel model(env);
   IloCplex cplex(model);
 
   return 0;
}
```

I have the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(myprog C CXX)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
find_package(CPLEX)
if (CPLEX_FOUND)
    add_definitions(-DIL_STD)
else()
    message (FATAL_ERROR "CPLEX not found!")
endif()

add_executable(myprog src/main.cpp )
target_include_directories(myprog PUBLIC ${CPLEX_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(myprog PUBLIC ${CPLEX_LIBRARIES})
set_target_properties(myprog PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-lconcert -lilocplex -lcplex -lpthread -ldl")
```

and `cmake/FindCPLEX.cmake`:

```
set (CPLEX_DIR "/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community201")

if (CPLEX_INCLUDE_DIR)
    set(CPLEX_FOUND TRUE)
    set(CPLEX_INCLUDE_DIRS "${CPLEX_INCLUDE_DIR};${CPLEX_CONCERT_INCLUDE_DIR}" )
    set(CPLEX_LIBRARIES "${CPLEX_ILO_LIBRARY};${CPLEX_CONCERT_LIBRARY};${CPLEX_LIBRARY};${CPLEX_PTHREAD_LIBRARY}" )
else (CPLEX_INCLUDE_DIR)

    find_path(CPLEX_INCLUDE_DIR
            NAMES ilcplex/cplex.h
            PATHS "${CPLEX_DIR}/cplex/include"
            )
    find_path(CPLEX_INCLUDE_ILCPLEX
            NAMES cplex.h
            PATHS "${CPLEX_DIR}/cplex/include/ilcplex"
            )

    find_path(CPLEX_CONCERT_INCLUDE_DIR
            NAMES ilconcert/ilomodel.h
            PATHS "${CPLEX_DIR}/concert/include"
            )

    find_path(CPLEX_INCLUDE_ILCONCERT
            NAMES ilomodel.h
            PATHS "${CPLEX_DIR}/concert/include/ilconcert"
            )

    find_library(CPLEX_LIBRARY
            cplex
            PATHS "${CPLEX_DIR}/cplex/lib/x86-64_sles10_4.1/static_pic"
            "${CPLEX_DIR}/cplex/lib/x86-64_darwin/static_pic/"
            "${CPLEX_DIR}/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic"
            )

    find_library(CPLEX_ILO_LIBRARY
            ilocplex
            PATHS "${CPLEX_DIR}/cplex/lib/x86-64_sles10_4.1/static_pic"
            "${CPLEX_DIR}/cplex/lib/x86-64_darwin/static_pic/"
            "${CPLEX_DIR}/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic"
            )

    find_library(CPLEX_CONCERT_LIBRARY
            concert
            PATHS "${CPLEX_DIR}/concert/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/"
                  "${CPLEX_DIR}/concert/lib/x86-64_sles10_4.1/static_pic"
                  "${CPLEX_DIR}/concert/lib/x86-64_darwin/static_pic/"
            )

    find_library( CPLEX_PTHREAD_LIBRARY
            pthread
            PATHS "/usr/lib"
            "/usr/lib64"
            "/lib"
            "/lib64"
            )

    find_library( CPLEX_DL_LIBRARY
            dl
            PATHS "/usr/lib"
            "/usr/lib64"
            "/lib"
            "/lib64"
            )

    set(CPLEX_COMPILER_FLAGS "-DIL_STD" CACHE STRING "Cplex Compiler Flags")

    include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
    find_package_handle_standard_args(CPLEX  DEFAULT_MSG
            CPLEX_LIBRARY CPLEX_INCLUDE_DIR CPLEX_CONCERT_INCLUDE_DIR CPLEX_ILO_LIBRARY CPLEX_CONCERT_LIBRARY)


    if(CPLEX_FOUND)
        set(CPLEX_INCLUDE_DIRS "${CPLEX_INCLUDE_DIR};${CPLEX_CONCERT_INCLUDE_DIR};${CPLEX_INCLUDE_ILCPLEX};${CPLEX_INCLUDE_ILCONCERT}" )
        set(CPLEX_LIBRARIES ${CPLEX_CONCERT_LIBRARY} ${CPLEX_ILOCPLEX_LIBRARY} ${CPLEX_LIBRARY} ${CPLEX_PTHREAD_LIBRARY} ${CPLEX_DL_LIBRARY})
    endif(CPLEX_FOUND)

    mark_as_advanced(CPLEX_INCLUDE_DIR CPLEX_LIBRARY CPLEX_CONCERT_INCLUDE_DIR CPLEX_ILO_LIBRARY CPLEX_CONCERT_LIBRARY CPLEX_PTHREAD_LIBRARY)

endif(CPLEX_INCLUDE_DIR)

message(STATUS "CPLEX_ILO_LIBRARY=${CPLEX_ILO_LIBRARY}")
message(STATUS "CPLEX_LIBRARIES=${CPLEX_LIBRARIES}")
message(STATUS "CPLEX_INCLUDE_DIRS=${CPLEX_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "concert=${concert}")
message(STATUS "cplex=${cplex}")
```

The CPLEX related CMake output is

```
-- Found CPLEX: /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/libcplex.a  
-- CPLEX_ILO_LIBRARY=/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/libilocplex.a
-- CPLEX_LIBRARIES=/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/concert/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/libconcert.a;/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/libcplex.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so
-- CPLEX_INCLUDE_DIRS=/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/cplex/include;/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/concert/include;/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/cplex/include/ilcplex;/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/concert/include/ilconcert
-- concert=
-- cplex=
```

The error is

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lconcert
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lilocplex
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcplex
```

Without the last line in `CMakeLists.txt`, the error is

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/myprog.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
/<my path>/src/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `IloCplex::IloCplex(IloModel)'
```

that is the linker finds the class `IloEnv` in `/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/concert/include/ilconcert/iloenv.h` and `IloModel` in `/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/concert/include/ilconcert/ilomodel.h` but not `IloCplex` in `/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/cplex/include/ilcplex/ilocplexi.h`.

Compiling from the command line works (formatted here for ease of reading):

```
$ for f in src/*.cpp; do 
... g++ -c -I/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/cplex/include 
... -I/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/concert/include 
... -Iinclude $f -o build/$(basename $f .cpp).o;
... done

$ unset OBJ_FILES 
$ for i in build/*.o; do OBJ_FILES="$i $OBJ_FILES"; done
$ g++ -I/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/cplex/include 
... -I/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/concert/include 
... -Iinclude  
... -L/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic 
... -L/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/concert/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic 
... $OBJ_FILES 
... -o progr  
... -lconcert -lilocplex -lcplex -lpthread -ldl
```

Comment: I think your `target_link_libraries` need to be declared as `STATIC`, for cplex and concert at least.  See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#cyclic-dependencies-of-static-libraries

Comment: Also I would recommend using `find_library` with `HINTS`.  Plus I would suggest that using `set_target_properties` to set linker inputs is deprecated.

Comment: @Den-Jason `STATIC` doesn't help. And `set_target_properties` was an attempt to solve the problem after `target_link_options` didn't work. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: `set_target_properties(LINK_FLAGS)` is definitely a wrong way to link libraries. Your `target_link_libraries` call should work. If you use `make` for build the project, pass `VERBOSE=1` option to it and look into **exact command lines** used for compiling and linking. In that command lines you may check actual include directories and libraries, compiler (make sure that `g++` points to the same compiler which is used by CMake) and other things.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Initially, I also expected just `target_link_libraries` to work, but they don't (very annoying!). The exact command lines are given in the question. The compiler is the same.

Comment: No, I don't mean command lines which you enter **manually** and which succeed. I mean command lines of the compiler and linker invocations **generated** (and executed) by CMake. As manual command lines work but generated one doesn't, it would be useful to **compare** them.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Oh, I see. CMake produces a lot of files. What I found suspicious: in `CMakeFiles/myprog.dir/build.make` there are lines `myprog: /<path>/libconcert.a` and `myprog: /<path>/libcplex.a`, but not for `ilocplex`. Also in `CMakeFiles/myprog.dir/link.txt` all other libraries appear (`libconcert.a`, `libcplex.a`, `libpthread.so`, `libdl.so`), but not `ilocplex`. I didn't find the place where the liker flags are set. Shall I look for something else in the makefiles?

Comment: You link your application with libraries listed in variable `CPLEX_LIBRARIES`, but don't add `CPLEX_ILO_LIBRARY` into this variable. Instead, you add `CPLEX_ILOCPLEX_LIBRARY` variable which is never set.

Comment: @Tsyvarev That's it, a stupid mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As Tsyvarev noted: instead of using `CPLEX_ILOCPLEX_LIBRARY` that is nowhere set, the variable `CPLEX_ILO_LIBRARY` should be used in the definition of `CPLEX_LIBRARIES`.